# Why did Windows XP disappear from the menu on my triple-boot system?

Tags: grub2, windows, dual-boot

I have Windows XP installed, followed by Mint 12 and finally Ubuntu 12.04. I did a `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` followed by `sudo update-grub`. On rebooting all was fine and the boot menu had Ubuntu 12.04, mem, windows, and finally Mint 12.

All was fine till now. Today wanted to boot into windows BUT found Wiindows XP missing from boot menu.

Tried `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` followed by `sudo update-grub`, BUT Windows XP is NOT FOUND.

Can someone help with what to do to restore Windows XP in the boot menu, please?

Comment: Content of **/boot/grub/menu.lst** please.

Comment: shouldn't be a menu.lst - closest is likely to be /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you not delete XP partition when installing Ubuntu 12.04?

I suggest you to download Grub Customizer and check your grub menu.

Install grub customizer 2.2 on ubuntu

Open the terminal and run the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Screen shot

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you cannot find Windows XP, probably you replace the partition with Ubuntu 12.04. If that so, find hardisk recovery to get back your data.

Answer (score 1):

You did the necessary things, but may be, try this: boot with the boot-repair Cd. (this is different from your method) . Read and download here  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair